# Why Duplicate "use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests; " in Laravel 5.6 Default Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

At the top of file, outside the class, we have:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
```

Inside the class, we have:

`use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;`

Why it is repeated?

Comment: All will be explained if you look at the Documentation

Comment: Those are called traits. You can use it's functionality whenever imported. AuthorizesRequests is used to check if the incoming request is done by an user who is allowed to or not. ValidatesRequests is used for validating user input. DispatchesJobs is used for dispatching jobs... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#dispatching-jobs

Comment: Thanks @MmynameStackflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [traits](http://php.net/traits), which add a defined set of functionality to the class. You can look up this functionality in the Laravel API docs:

- https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.html
- https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html
- https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.html

The `use` statements up the top are part of PHP's [namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces), which you'll want to get familiar with - this pattern is used all over Laravel's code. Having the `use Foo\Bar\Hello\World` up the top of the file allows you to do stuff like `new World` instead of typing out the full `new \Foo\Bar\Hello\World` throughout the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we already have use statements at the top of the file, why we add them again inside classes - this bit is confusing me.

Comment: @SuperMike The `use` statements at the top (outside the class) are basically saying "When I type `new World` *within* the class, I *really* mean to be using the `\Foo\Bar\Hello\World` class. It's a shortcut, basically.

Comment: Above the class are [imports](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), in the class are traits.

Comment: Thanks @Devon for explaining the last bit :)